# Showing that a plane is an invariant subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ under a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question is

> Let $T: \mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be defined by $T(v) = Av$ wheere $A$ is given by
>
> $A = \frac 13   \begin{bmatrix}
>         2 & -1 & 2 \\
>         2 & 2 & -1 \\
>         -1 & 2 & 2 \\
>         \end{bmatrix}$

Show that the plane $U : x + y + z = 0$ is an invariant subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ under $T$.

Well this plane is the nullspace with special solutions

$$ s_1 =\begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        -1 \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
and $$ s_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        0 \\
       -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

How would I approach this problem? Should I find the eigenspaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an arbitrary vector on the plane, say 
\begin{bmatrix}
        x\\
        y \\
        -x-y\\
        \end{bmatrix}
And apply the linear transformation to it, then show that the new vector is on the plane